# Problems with video playback in iPad

Tags: ipad, mpmoviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a MPMoviePlayerView but I can't play the video files, I don't have a device yet to try it on, now I'm testing with simulator, I don't know if this is the cause.

So far I've been able to present the view and it shows the first frame of the video, but if I click play, it doesn't play I can move the progress bar and it shows the images, but there's no movement, it stays still.
Has anyone experienced something like this?

The code of my UIViewController goes like this:

```
NSURL *movieURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"video.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerView=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerView];
```

As I said, it shows up, I can move the progress bar back and forth, I see a still image, but no movement. Am I missing something here? or is it the simulator?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like this was one plugin error or something in the simulator, it works fine now.